# Running a new Play application with the Activator 1.3.10 offline distribution

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to run a new Play application that I created with the [Activator 1.3.10 offline distribution](https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.10/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip) on a machine that doesn't have an Internet connection. When I `cd` into the project directory and run `activator`, the project tries to resolve dependencies by looking in online repositories (such as repo.typesafe.com and repo1.maven.org), but these dependencies are in the `$ACTIVATOR_HOME/repository` folder. Why is this "offline" distribution trying to go to the Internet to find dependencies that it has locally? This behavior didn't change after I went into the `~/.sbt/repositories` file and removed the following lines:

`maven central
typesafe-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
typesafe-ivy-releasez: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases...`

How do I get this project to actually run offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On a computer that is connected to the Internet:

   1. [Install Activator 1.3.10](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing) and [create a new Play application](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication).
   2. Modify the `$PROJECT_HOME/build.sbt` file as needed.
   3. Run `activator run` from `$PROJECT_HOME`
   4. Put the following on a portable medium (e.g., CD or flash drive):

      - [Activator offline distribution](https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.10/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip)
      - `$PROJECT_HOME/build.sbt`
      - The entire contents of the `~/.ivy2/cache/` directory
      - [compiler-interface.jar](http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.11/jars/:compiler-interface.jar) for sbt 0.13.11
2. On the computer that is not connected to the Internet:

   1. Transfer the Ivy cache contents to the `~/.ivy2/cache/` directory
   2. Create an `$ACTIVATOR_HOME/repository/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.11/srcs/` directory
   3. Transfer `compiler-interface.jar` to the above directory
   4. Install the Activator offline distribution and create a new Play application
   5. Using the same `build.sbt` file, run `activator run` from `$PROJECT_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

That's because its trying to check for latest update. if there is any outdated jar it will be updated. try to disable auto update.

To disable. Go to .activator\1.3.10 folder[example: In windows 7 C:\Users\XXX.activator\1.3.10]. open activatorconfig.txt or create one and add -"**Dactivator.checkForUpdates=false**"

NOTE: haven't tried it by myself

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
offline := true
```

in your `project/plugins.sbt`
Source: https://twitter.com/jroper/status/327679374205800449